# PDF parser and OPcodeExtraction

Tags: malware, detection, shellcode, pdf

I'm performing an university project on malware detection. Specifically I need:

```
  - extract javascript from a PDF,                                          
  - put it in the right order,                                               
  - extract opcode sequences of a possible embedded shellcode using for 
    example libemu.
```

In particular the parsing process has to deal with obfuscated/encrypted 
 javascript and  even with javascript not located in normal positions referred 
 by the documentation.
 Any suggestion on how I can perform these tasks will be very appreciated. Is 
 there something already implemented?
 Thanks very much.

Comment: There are several papers about such kind of analysis where you can also find references to the tools used and maybe also code. Search for example for Wepawet and PJScan.

Comment: I know these two papers, the problem is that PJScan for example, during the parsing process doesn't look to other locations where javascript can be hidden, for example metadata items.@ Steffen Ullrich

Comment: If you already know these papers then why do you ask such a broad question which suggests that you know not much yet? Please edit your question so that it shows what you already know and which specific problems you have with existing tools  and approaches instead of letting others waste their time with stuff you already know.

Comment: @Myke PJScan is open source.  You could create your own fork of it and modify it to look where you want it to in addition to its normal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Try Didier Stevens' PDF tools which should allow you to do this via CLI instead of GUI: https://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/pdf-tools/. Also, Didier did a lot of work on obfuscation methods so they should help you with most malformed situations.

Answer (score 0):

Try those tools as stated [here](https://zeltser.com/tools-for-malicious-pdf-analysis/).

[PDF stream dumper](https://zeltser.com/pdf-stream-dumper-malicious-file-analysis/)  is recommended because [the tools still actively support](https://github.com/dzzie/pdfstreamdumper) . The github source mentioned command line support.

```
PdfStreamDumper currently only supports one command line option which is /extract
    usage: pdfstreamdumper "c:\blah blah\bad.pdf" /extract "c:\some folder"
        When run in this mode, it will load the pdf file (interface visible) extract all of
        of the streams it could process without error to the folder specified and then exit.
    The folder need not exist, it will build the path to it if it can. The files will be 
    named stream_x.ext where ext is the relevant file type extension if it can be determined.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I saw that this is a gui program. Are there some API such that I can use it programmatically? Thanks in advance.@mootmoot

Comment: I found out another  tool that support command line, namely peepdf. Do you think that it could be as useful as PDF stream dumper?@mootmoot

Comment: @Myke You need to try them out to be sure. There is no perfect tools out there. It is common to mix different tools for malware analysis.